# Inequality problem, please help me!

Tags: inequality

For $a\neq b\neq c\neq a$, prove that:
$\left ( \frac{a+2015}{b-c} \right )^2+\left ( \frac{b+2015}{a-c} \right )^2+\left ( \frac{c+2015}{b-a} \right )^2\geq2$.

Comment: I bet it holds even if you replace $2015$ with $1$. Have you given it a try? Might be much easier to prove that instead (and obviously, that expression is smaller than the original one).

Comment: You can eliminate the $2015$ without loss of generality, setting $a'=a+2015,b'=b+2015,c'=c+2015$ b/c the pairwise differences stay invariant.

Comment: @barakmanos not necessarily smaller, if negatives are allowed! The translation suggestion works though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\dfrac{a+2015}{b-c}\right)^2\ge 2$$

since $$a+2015\to a,b+2015\to b,c+2015\to c$$
then we only prove
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\dfrac{a}{b-c}\right)^2\ge 2$$
then 
Let
$$\dfrac{a}{b-c}=x,\dfrac{b}{c-a}=y,\dfrac{c}{a-b}=z$$
so
we have
$$\begin{cases}
a-xb+xc=0\\
ya+b-yc=0\\
za-zb-c=0
\end{cases}\Longrightarrow \begin{vmatrix}
1&-x&x\\
y&1&-y\\
z&-z&-1
\end{vmatrix}=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow -1-xyz+xyz-xz-xy-yz=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow  xy+yz+xz=-1$$
since
$$(x+y+z)^2\ge 0$$
so
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge -2(xy+yz+xz)=2$$